# JHipster: how to redirect to another page after login success?

Tags: redirect, authentication, jhipster

Trying to change the default behaviour of JHipster default application gateway, I'm looking for the correct way to redirect to a custom login_success.html page. Is there any official tutorial or workaround for this?

I tried as follows but nothing happens, by editing the login function in the **login.component.ts**; not even errors:

```
login() {
    this.loginService.login({
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        rememberMe: this.rememberMe
    }).then(() => {
        this.authenticationError = false;
        this.activeModal.dismiss('login success');
        if (this.router.url === '/register' || (/^\/activate\//.test(this.router.url)) ||
            (/^\/reset\//.test(this.router.url))) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        }

        this.eventManager.broadcast({
            name: 'authenticationSuccess',
            content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
        });

        // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
        // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
        // const redirect = this.stateStorageService.getUrl();
        const redirect = '/something.html';
        console.log('Before Redirect');
        if (redirect) {
            console.log('Redirect');
            this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(null);
            // this.router.navigate([redirect]);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        this.authenticationError = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using **JWT** tokens

Comment: if you want to redirect to a static html page (different than index.html) it's going to be more complex than staying in same angular application using routes. I would rather adapt what JHipster does rather than working around it.

Comment: Well, the idea was to simply redirect the user to it's personal info page.
Hence, for instance there are 2 cases:
1-user is ADMIN ---> login ---> monitoring-staff
2-normal user ---> login ---> personal info page

Would it be simpler to get this by providing some new routes, based on user's role?

Comment: Yes this would be much easier, have a look at login.component.ts

Comment: I did, but still not getting the point why no error is thrown after a static url set as the redirect in the login function. See the question body.

Comment: Have you defined the /something.html route ? The browser console should show router trace.

Comment: I didn't, thinking it would have at least tried to find that url and show an error not founding it. I'm a bit new to JHipster and Angular, should I define that rout in Angular or in Spring Boot?

Comment: It's an angular route and it should point to an angular component with its template. I recommend you learn more about angular routing and components, without the basis you will go nowhere.

Comment: I'd suggest that you delete this question as it's not going to help anybody

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In login.component.ts find:

```
        // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
        // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
        const redirect = this.stateStorageService.getUrl();
        if (redirect) {
            this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(null);
            this.router.navigate([redirect]);
        }
```

and change to:

```
        // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
        // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
        const redirect = this.stateStorageService.getUrl();
        if (redirect) {
            this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(null);
            this.router.navigate([redirect]);
        } else {
            this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(null);
            this.router.navigate(['/panel']);
        }
```

where '/panel' is the page you want to redirect.